# Vi Editor A complete Block Deletion

Tags: vi

I have been using vi editor since few days. I found this editor to be quite useful to program in c. I have a he following question.

Is there any option to delete a block in vi ediotr. By block i mean a if-block or a while-block or a for block?

Comment: Are you referring to plain vanilla VI or to VIM version ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the block delimited by a blank line, you can do

```
d}
```

d - for delete
} - till end of block

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do exactly what you want(editor detects logical block of code and mark it).

What you can do(only when you using vi improved(vim)) is to enter visual mode("v" key), highlight code with arrows(or h,j,k,l) and press "d" to delete.

Comment: that's vim, if OP is using vanilla VI there is no visual mode

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry. Of course it's only vim but some people(especially beginners to vi/m) might not see the difference so I'll leave post.

Comment: agree. However does the old school way (with marks) work with vim ? At the moment I've got no chance to test it

Answer (score 0):

I used to navigate to end block with `%` (on the opening bracket), setting a mark (`ma`), navigate back to beginning of block (still with `%` or by `''`) and then delete till mark (`d'a`)

If you're usign improved version of VI (namely VIM) there are quicker ways.